# PHP include statement not working?

Tags: php

Just started learning PHP and Wordpress.

Why isn't my PHP include statement working in the following `header.php` file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title>
<?php include 'functions.php';?>
<?php if( is_page(1406)): ?>
<?php wp_title(' - ', true, 'right'); ?> <?php get_1406_page_title(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php wp_title(' - ', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
<?php endif; ?> 
</title>
.
.
.
```

I need to call `get_1406_page_title()` which is located in the `functions.php`. The above code produces empty page, and when I remove the include line the title is empty.

Here is the `get_1406_page_title()` from `functions.php`:

```
function get_1406_page_title()
{
    $title = "Page title here";
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to include your theme's `function.php` - it is loaded automatically.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I should look for the problem elsewhere, maybe my `get_1406_page_title()`.

Comment: Enable the [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to find the real reason.

Comment: You do not need `wp_title()`, it is a supported theme option

Comment: Updated questions with `get_1406_page_title()` source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your current code you

- do not need to include `functions.php`, it is automatically done
- Because `get_1406_page_title()` returns it's output, you need to echo the result from the function if you need to display the result

  ```
  echo get_1406_page_title();
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much. How come `bloginfo('name');` doesn't require `echo`? It also returns a string.

Comment: No, `bloginfo()` echos output, check the [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/). I think you are thinking about `get_bloginfo()`

Comment: Ah OK... got it. I will do the same, wrap `get_1406_page_title()` into `1406_title()` with just additional `echo` to make is cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: Great idea. Good luck with your project. Enjoy ;-)